# Is it bad code to return whole dataframes? What are the pythonic ways to separate preprocessing and modeling?

Tags: python, pandas, performance

I am reading a colleague's code who has separated the preprocessing and model building modules into separate .py files like shown below:

```py
def read_datasourceX_data(path, filenames):
    """
    A function to perform read data
    :rtype data: pd.DataFrame
    """
    return datasourceX_df

def match_datasourceX_to_someID(datasourceX_df, datasourceID_df, x, y):
    """
    A function to perform read datasourceX_df and datasourceID_df
    :rtype data: pd.DataFrame
    """
    return matched_df
```

And there's a lot of dataframes being returned by these functions. It increases readability. Is this pythonic?

Edit:  I imagine, using apply() is more pythonic, but how would I organize my code without compromising readability?

Edit: For a clearer question: Between using apply() and passing a dataframe to a function which returns another (equally large) dataframe, which would you choose. Yes it is somewhat opinion-based because that is the nature of 'best practices'. Please do not flag this for being opinion-based.

Comment: Depends on what functions do and how they are called. Without specifics, this question may border on *too broad* or *opinion-based*, both off-topic on SO. Please post a [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) use case.

Comment: Also, Pandas/Numpy programming involving data science operations is fundamentally different from general Python programming.

Comment: Please elaborate in an answer what you mean by 'depends on what the functions do'. The second comment is not relevant to the post. Updating my question to state in no uncertain what the question is.

Comment: When you say "return whole dataframes" are you concerned about data copying? If so, are you aware that all that is returned is a reference to the dataframe?